# How can I remove last comma and all spaces from string, then sanitize it using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the string from input field, then format and sanitize it.

The strings I want to get is natural number separated by commas without any spaces.
First I want to remove all spaces and last comma.
I mean if the formatted string is not match what I want, I want it to return empty string.

```
//OK examples(without any spaces)
1,2,123,45,7
132,1,555,678
```

```
//NG examples
aaa,111,2365
1,2,123,45,7,
-1,2,123,45,7,,,
1, 2, 123, 45,  7
```

First I want to remove spaces and last comma
1,  235, 146,  => 1,235,146

I tried code below

```
$input = str_replace(' ', '', $input);
rtrim($input, ',');
if (preg_match('/^\d(?:,\d+)*$/', $input)) {
    return $input;
}
return '';
```

This one, if the string has spaces after last comma, it returns empty string.

```
1,2,123,45,7,   => //returns empty string.
```

I want to format this to '1,2,123,45,7'.

Sorry for my messy explanation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace spaces and trim commas and spaces at beginning or end:

```
$result = str_replace(' ', '', trim($string, ', '));
```

Or:

```
$result = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $string), ',');
```

Then if you only want numbers and commas (no letters etc.) maybe:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[\d,]+$/', $string)) {
    //error
}
```

However this will not error on a single number with no commas.

Comment: Close, your trim needs a space: `trim($string, ', ')` - now you are golden :) - [Example](https://3v4l.org/YbU19) - Why? Because trim gets executed first, so you still have the spaces in there.

Comment: @Pilan I edited that before your comment and added another example.  I thought `trim` always trimmed spaces and additional, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\s+|,+\s*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/1fuC4K/2)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,+                       One or more ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

PHP:

```
preg_replace('/\s+|,+\s*$/', '', $input)
```